# Appending custom geometry node trees from a .blend file with bpy

Tags: python, add-on

I am currently coding an addon to dynamically smear objects with geometry nodes, and I have the whole thing done but I cannot figure out how to import the geometry nodes tree into the file. I have tried to something like this

```
USER = Path(resource_path('USER'))
src = USER / "scripts/addons" / "AutoSmear"

file_path = src / "data.blend"
inner_path = "NodeTree"
object_name = "Smear Mesh"
bpy.ops.wm.link_append(
    filepath=str(file_path / inner_path / object_name),
    directory=str(file_path / inner_path),
    filename=object_name
    )
```

but when I do this, it gives me this error

```
AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'view_layer'
```

I have tried other methods too, but all of the give me similar errors. Is there something that I have coded wrong here or is this method outdated? Sorry if the answer is obvious, this is the first thing that I am coding.

Comment: Can you share your full script? What section of your script are you trying to run this code from? `_RestrictContext` generally occurs when you try to change any data at `register()`

Comment: @Psyonic yea, heres the full code: https://pastebin.com/3WM5SF4A I have tried doing it at the very start of the code, and in the register()

Comment: gotta keep it out of `register()` for a start. I'm assuming you are trying to pull in your GN tree at Blender start up? This is not a good idea and is Restricted intentionally. Instead you should have a button that does this work when the user wants to activate your addon in their workflow. Make a button that is called something like "AutoSmear" and when clicked does this initial work (appends the node tree) and shows all the other buttons. This way the user is intentionally knowing that they are activating this function.

Comment: Also, you should use the `poll()` method to restrict your addon from operating if a ARMATURE is not the currently selected object

Comment: So I could put the code that I posted in the original post into a button (with some changes obviously), it would work then? Also never heard of 'poll()', thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can't say it **will** work, but it will not work as you have it now :P

Comment: tysm, after a lot of trouble shooting, it works! Now my addon is basically ready to ship thanks to you, so many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :)